# How to use db API addExpression

Tags: views, database

I am trying to find a way of creating a view of both a custom entity type and a node. I was following this as a guide: https://drupal.org/node/748844 (see the way end for the D7 implementation, I have quoted it below, but for some reason, its not fully displaying...)

I am trying to understand this line

```
$query2->addExpression(':the_group_type', 'Type', array(':the_group_type' => 'Group'));
```

I see from online documentation that addExpression adds an expression to a list of fields, which I would assume means something like SUM(quantity). But I don't understand what the addExpression lines (there are actually two of them) are doing in this code.

Code listed below:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_pre_execute()
 */
function YOUR_MODULE_NAME_views_pre_execute(&$view){
    if($view->name == 'YOUR_VIEW_NAME'){
    //extracts my nodes
    $query2 = db_select('node', 'node');
    $query2->leftJoin('location_instance', 'location_instance', 'node.vid = location_instance.vid');
    $query2->leftJoin('location', 'location', 'location_instance.lid  = location.lid');

    //created and nid are the same fields used by my_view query
    $query2->addField('node', 'title', 'users_name');  
    $query2->addField('node', 'nid', 'uid');  
    $query2->addField('location', 'latitude', 'location_latitude');  
    $query2->addField('location', 'longitude', 'location_longitude');  
    $query2->addExpression(':the_group_type', 'Type', array(':the_group_type' => 'Group'));

    //set some conditions if necessary
    $query2->condition('node.type', 'group', '=')
           ->condition('node.status', 1, '=');

    $query1 = $view->build_info['query'];
    $query1 ->addExpression(':the_user_type', 'Type', array(':the_user_type' => 'User'));

    //union custom query with my_view default query
    $query2->union($query1, 'UNION ALL');


    //in order to prevent Cardinality violation errors i have to make a "total" query
    $total_query = db_select($query2,'total')->fields('total');

    //update views query and count_query with my new query.
    $view->build_info['query'] = $total_query;
    $view->build_info['count_query'] = $view->build_info['query']; //count_query is necessary for the pager
  }
}
```

Comment: [online documentation here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQueryInterface%3A%3AaddExpression/7). Google phrase: `addExpression site:api.drupal.org` - hope it'll help you in the future.

Comment: I did google it and I saw that page. I just don't understand what the arguements are here and what it is doing. How is this a "arbitrary string that is valid SQL"?

Comment: Sorry, but that's just that. If you need a definition of "arbitrary string" or "valid SQL", it will be damn hard to help you. It would be easier if you could narrow your question giving example of what you need, SQL you expected to get generated, code you are using and the way it fails your expectations. Now we can see your code, but your question basically calls to rewrite manual.

Answer (score 2):

Any valid SQL expression is allowed, and that includes placeholders (like in that code), literal values, or SQL functions calls (including aggregate functions, such as `COUNT(*)`).

`$query2->addExpression(':the_group_type', 'Type', array(':the_group_type' => 'Group'))` is equivalent, in plain SQL, to `'Group' AS Type`.
It is an expression that is widely used in the Views module. For example, if you enable the "Add Views signature to all SQL queries" option, the query executed by the Views module will be similar to the following one. (This is the query I get for the front page view.)

```
SELECT node.sticky AS node_sticky, node.created AS node_created, node.nid AS nid, 'frontpage:default' AS view_name
FROM 
{node} node
WHERE (( (node.promote <> '0') AND (node.status = '1') ))
ORDER BY node_sticky DESC, node_created DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

The `'frontpage:default' AS view_name` part is added using `SelectQuery::addExpression()` in a way similar to what the code you show does.